# How to label my axis using words in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, svg, axis-labels

I would like to make a bar chart, where every bar represents the frequency of a certain word.

My data is an array of objects, with each having the property `word` and `freq`.

I declared my axis like that :

```
    let echelleX = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.word))
        .range([marges.left, width - marges.right])
        .padding(0.1);
```

And called it :

```
     svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","axeX")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
        .call(axeX)
        .selectAll("text")
        .attr("font-weight", "normal")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".5em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");
```

I then add my bars to the svg :

```
    svg.append("g").selectAll(".barre").data(data).enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "barre")
    .attr("x", (d,i) => echelleX(d.word))
    .attr("y", (d) => echelleY(d.freq))
    .attr("width", 2.5)
    .attr("height", d => height - echelleY(d.freq))
    .attr("fill","steelblue");
```

But the result is this :

[image]

When I change this line

```
.attr("x", (d,i) => echelleX(d.word))
```

To

```
.attr("x", (d,i) => marges.left + i*3)
```

I get this, which is better, but the labels of the axis still don't match.

[image]

I checked the documentation of d3.scaleBand and tried a few tweaks but I can't seem to make it work the way I would want to. What am I missing? I would like every bar (`d.freq`) to have its corresponding label (`d.word`) underneath it on the axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Band scales are ordinal instead of linear, which means you need to provide every possible value to the domain instead of just the min/max. D3 cannot interpolate ordinal values.

Try this

```
.domain(data.map(d => d.word))
```

You will also have to revert the change you made to the `x` attr, the band scale should take care of that.

EDIT: Made the mistake of thinking `d3.map` did the same thing as array map.

Comment: So your solution didn't really work, none of the bars were showing. I had to use this : `.domain(d3.set(data.map(function(d){return d.word;} )).values())`

The thing is, I copied this code from another example I found online, but have no idea why it works. Could you explain why? What's the difference between using `data.map` and `d3.set(data.map[...])`?

Comment: I probably missed some small thing but what i said about ordinal scales was true, if you create a jsfiddle with the appropriate data i would gladly show you how to do it. The only difference is that `set` returns unique values, but your original data shouldn't contain duplicates anyways.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer @Eric Guan, I just got back to my computer. Here is a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/yjw5aojr/

Comment: My mistake, thought d3.map was same thing as array.map. https://jsfiddle.net/yjw5aojr/1/